# comparing a list of tuples python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples in python of the form `[(word, sym) , (word, sym)....]`.

Let's assume the symbol is either `A` or `B`. I want to return all words for which  the list contains two tuples of the form `("example", A)` and `("example", B)`. So basically one word paired with BOTH `A` and `B`. I'm assuming this can be done using list comprehension. I can do this to get all words where the symbol is A:

`[x[0] for x in self.list if x[1] == "A"]`

and in a similar fashion obtain the list of words where the symbol is B however, I'm not sure how to compare the two lists.

Would I simply use `if word in listA and word in listB`?

Comment: Yes, it works but it returns duplicates tho. I'm not sure how to get rid of them

Comment: If the question contained some example of the form of valid Python that can be pasted as part of an answer, this would be fairly straightforward to answer.

Comment: of course it would have duplicates because you are iterating through all your items so it would appear twice(as it should). call `set(list)` on the list to get rid of duplicates, or do a set comp instead of a list comp (replace `[]` with `{}`)

Comment: Minor style note: It's much nicer (and usually faster) to unpack the tuples to names, instead of leaving them tupled and using anonymous indexing. So your list comprehension would be: `[word for word, sym in self.list if sym == "A"]` The names make the code more self-documenting instead of strewing magic numbers around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming order is unimportant, this is a great use case for `set` intersections:

```
setA = {word for word, sym in self.list if sym == "A"}
setB = {word for word, sym in self.list if sym == "B"}

AB_words = setA & setB  # Preserves only those words found in both input sets
```

Then if you need to test if any given word is a common word, it's a trivial `set` membership test:

```
if word in AB_words:
```